# Do we accept or close recipe requests?

Tags: discussion, scope

Seasoned Advice has [excluded recipe requests for various reasons](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/728/what-types-of-recipe-questions-are-allowed). One of the most important one being that asking for recipes is fundamentally opinion-based and therefore not a good fit for the site and the SE system in general.

Should we adapt this reasoning and rule for Coffee SE as well?

Comment: (inspired by https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/5241/simulated-vietnamese-coffee-in-bobba-bars)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I appreciate the Seasoned Advice stance and think we should use the same basic policy here for questions about "how to make..." something: reject the opinion-based "what's the best recipe for..." type of question but encourage questions relating more to technique or ingredient-list. As with SA there's a little bit of interpretation or leeway in that policy, and I think we'll have to do the same here.

The [inspirational example linked in comment above](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/5241/simulated-vietnamese-coffee-in-bobba-bars) could be interpreted as "recreating" or "substitution" -- the question I think could be steered toward "what ingredients could I use to make it taste like that" and be a helpful and productive question. In fact, I might comment on that question to steer it that way. More generally I would (personally) support or encourage edits or comments to steer questions along the lines of the Seasoned Advice policy.

Fortunately I think the space of "recipe requests" will be less problematic in Coffee by nature than in Seasoned Advice. That said, we should be vigilant about opinion-oriented pitfalls of brands or ingredients based on personal taste or preference.

Comment: Post edited accordingly (and answered). Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I think we should allow recipes. There are several objective factors which can be considered for coffee and which are also used for competitions: texture, acidity, sweetness, bitterness and balance. While brewing recipes are also somewhat subject to opinion, it is nowhere nearly as controversial as with regular cooking recipes.

Comment: This question wasn’t inspired by a post about the influence of the diverse factors like roast and grind size - as they are somewhat measurable or at least can be answerable without the individual preferences as main factor, they would probably be even acceptable on Seasoned Advice. But I was talking about a “give me a recipe for <coffee drink thingy>” requests.